# Mountain Lion overheating issue have to do with launchd/Python?

Tags: python, cpu-usage, osx-mountain-lion, launchd, overheating

So, Ever since I installed ML, my MacBook Air has been running SUPER hot.
Opened up activity monitor, and everything seemed to be pretty normal, until I had it refresh every .5 seconds... and then I started seeing some interesting things.

A 'Python' process appears and is terminated several times a second, and uses TONS of CPU 70-110. 
It's parent process is 'launchd' - and when I sample the process, there is a lot going on with Python.

http://db.tt/ovuX3hZM

These appear and disappear too quickly to get one... this one only happened to be using 70 ish percent of CPU... but they consistently hit 100-110%.

http://db.tt/ovuX3hZMg

The parent process... launchd. lots of context switches and UNIX system calls... What is the deal here?

(photo goes here when I earn the street cred)

The sample of launchd.

ANY help here could be of help to not only me, but possibly many others experiencing decreased battery life and warmer laps these days because of this Mountain Lion weirdness.

PLEASE HELP!

PS - I'd put the screen grabs inline, but i don't have enough street cred yet.

Comment: This is the grab of my launchd sample http://db.tt/GTK6xTck

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things to check and/or change here.

Go to your User Account pane in System Preferences and look under "Login Items" and see what's there.  One of them might be the wacky item that's trying to run Python.

If you don't see anything out of place there, [then check out "`launchctl list`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430402/how-to-check-the-statusrunning-stopped-of-a-process-daemon-in-mac) at the Terminal and see if you see something suspicious there.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else experiences this problem, its usually caused by a change of log level to debug for launchctl. Running this should fix it:

```
sudo launchctl log level error
```

Even though on my machine I am still not sure what changed the log level...